# not able to read PDF docuemnet in langchain

Tags: pdf, loader, langchain

trying to read a PDF document in langchain but getting the below error . Pypdf is also installed. Can you please advise how to resolve it

```
langchain.document_loaders.PyPDFLoader

file_path="C:/Users/gbzr7856/Desktop/LanChain/Data Science from Scratch.pdf"

pdf_loader = PyPDFLoader(file_path=file_path)
```

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[46], line 1
----> 1 pdf_loader = PyPDFLoader(file_path=file_path)

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\langchain\Lib\site-packages\langchain\document_loaders\pdf.py:157, in PyPDFLoader.**init**(self, file_path, password, headers, extract_images)
153 except ImportError:
154     raise ImportError(
155         "pypdf package not found, please install it with " "`pip install pypdf`"
156     )
--> 157 super().**init**(file_path, headers=headers)
158 self.parser = PyPDFParser(password=password, extract_images=extract_images)

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\langchain\Lib\site-packages\langchain\document_loaders\pdf.py:100, in BasePDFLoader.**init**(self, file_path, headers)
98         self.file_path = str(temp_pdf)
99 elif not os.path.isfile(self.file_path):
--> 100     raise ValueError("File path %s is not a valid file or url" % self.file_path)

ValueError: File path C:/Users/gbzr7856/Desktop/LanChain/Data Science from Scratch.pdf is not a valid file or url

`i want to read the PDF document`

Answer (score 0):

From the exception, you ought to take two actions.

1. `pip install pypdf`
2. The `file_path` is not correctly specified. Try this

```py
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader

loader = PyPDFLoader("example_path/layout-parser-paper.pdf")  # Don't forget the double-quote
pages = loader.load_and_split()
```